# 200 ок вместо 404, как исправить или добавить else?

Tags: php

Написал скрипт сайта, адреса следующего вида
вася.ру/1234567

Глянул поиск, появилась куча не существующих страниц вида 
вася.ру/contact.html
вася.ру/contact/ и много других вариантов, при этом страницы на самом деле не существует но отдается код 200.

Файл .htaccess выглядит так

```
## Application Handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ 2.php?a=$1  [QSA,NC,L]

## Error 404 ##
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?a=404
```

Как научить скрипт выставлять 404 ошибку на не существующих страницах?

Сам сайт формируется **с помощью cURL запросов**, из-за этого и появляется множество не существующих страниц...

Помогите разобраться, спасибо!

Добавил после скрипта который отображает результат с помощью echo $postResult; код `...?> <?php header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'); ?>` теперь 404 отдается серверу. Но если страница есть, появляется сообщение об ошибке - header уже был передан т.е. пытается сработать 404, но в результате 200 ок как и нужно. Можно с помощью else сделать, чтобы при ответе 200 ок, 404 не отдавалась? Спасибо!

Comment: `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?a=404` а как вы думаете зачем это правило?

Comment: думаю, что это редирект который сработает при получении 404 ошибки

Comment: @MicroRu в этом index.php возвращай 404 код при a=404

Comment: Я не знаю как вернуть 404 ошибку если страницы нет, сейчас возвращает 200 ок. Нужно видимо какое-то условие написать, чтобы все кроме вася.ру/1234567 вася.ру/1000567 вася.ру/1234567000 и т.д. считалось за 404

Comment: Добавил после скрипта который отображает результат с помощью         echo $postResult; код `...?>
<?php 
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
?>` теперь 404 отдается серверу. Но если страница есть, появляется сообщение об ошибке - header уже был передан т.е. пытается сработать 404, но в результате 200 ок как и нужно. Можно с помощью else сделать, чтобы при ответе 200 ок, 404 не отдавалась? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в начало своего файла 2.php следующий код:

```
// в этот массив добавьте ссылки на все несуществующие страницы
$nonExistentPages = array('contact.html', 'contact');
if (in_array($_REQUEST['a'], $nonExistentPages)) {
    header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} 404 Not Found");
    // если нужно выдавать какой-то информационный контент, 
    // делайте это здесь.
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что этих страниц может быть сотни и заранее они мне не известны т.к. получаю их через cURL... Ваш код мне тоже очень нужен для другой цели. Спасибо! Пока думаю вставить метатег index, nofolow

Comment: Моей главной целью было ответить на ваш вопрос "Как вернуть ошибку 404, если страницы не существует". А по каким критериям вы будете определять существует она или нет - решайте сами. Вариант с проверкой по массиву приведен мною для примера.